# npm install error - Unexpected string package.json

Tags: json, node.js, gruntjs, assemble, package.json

Gurus.I running a Grunt in my project. But I get this error.

> sh-3.2# grunt
>   Loading "assemble.js" tasks...ERROR SyntaxError: /usr/local/bin/hui/dashboard/package.json: Unexpected string
>   Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
>   Aborted due to warnings.

This is my package.json:

> {
>     "name": "Flatkit",
>     "version": "1.0.3",
>     "description": "Bootstrap 4 Web App UI Kit with AngularJS",
>     "scripts": {
>       "start": "node node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server -o"
>     },
>     "keywords": [],
>     "repository": "https://gitlab.com/Heyflat/flatkit.git",
>     "author": "Flatfull",
>     "license": "Envato REGULAR LICENSE",
>     "dependencies": {},
>     "devDependencies": {
>       "grunt": "^0.4.5",
>       "grunt-assemble": "^0.4.0",
>       "grunt-bump": "0.0.15",
>       "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
>       "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
>       "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0",
>       "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.14.0",
>       "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.3.0",
>       "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
>       "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.5.1",
>       "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
>       "grunt-sass": "^1.0.0",
>       "grunt-usemin": "^3.1.1",
>       "http-server": "^0.6.1"
>       "node-sass": "0.9.4"
>     }
>   }

Any ideas what's wrong with my package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"," is missed. "http-server": "^0.6.1"**`,`**

Answer (score 1):

```
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.1.1",
    "http-server": "^0.6.1"
    "node-sass": "0.9.4"
```

Missing `,`